# Как проверить содержимое файла перед записью?

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Есть php скрипт, который заносит значения в файл txt типа:

**name:02-02-2016**

**name_3:02-03-2016**

Как сделать следующее:

Проверяем, есть ли **name_3** в файле, и если есть - обновляем второе значение - в нашел случае это 02-03-2016. Если же name_3 нет в файле - то добавляем его.

За ранее спасибо.

Comment: Только прочитать весь файл, поискать требуемое, выполнить действие в памяти, сбросить изменённую часть обратно в файл. Если файл великоват - читать блоками. Если обновлённые данные не длиннее старых - постараться обойтись записью поверх.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит использовать для хранения данных json-формат.

Рассмотрим такой пример.

Допустим, вы храните данные в `test.txt`. Запишем массив данных в файл, а потом снова прочитаем файл, изменим одну строку и добавим одну строку. Будем разделять имя и дату по двоеточию. Поэтому нужно гарантировать, что в имени этого символа не будет.

```
<?php
// Записываем первоначальные данные
$json = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$arr = ['name:02-02-2010', 'name_1:12-02-2016', 'name_10:02-09-2006',
 'name_5:11-11-2011', 'name_3:20-02-2002'];
foreach($arr as $data){
    $spl = split(':', $data, 2);
    $array['names'][$spl[0]] = $spl[1];
}
$new_json = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents('test.txt', $new_json);

// Снова читаем файл
$json = file_get_contents('test.txt');
// Выводим данные, что записали 1-й раз
echo $json . "<br/><br/>";
$array = json_decode($json, true);
// Одна строка со старым именем, а другая с новым.
$arr = ['name_1:30-01-2010', 'name_666:06-06-2006'];
foreach($arr as $data){
    $spl = split(':', $data, 2);
    $array['names'][$spl[0]] = $spl[1];
}
$new_json = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// Выводим изменённые данные
echo $new_json;
file_put_contents('test.txt', $new_json);
?>
```

Вывод будет такой:

```
{"names":{"name":"02-02-2010","name_1":"12-02-2016","name_10":"02-09-2006","name_5":"11-11-2011","name_3":"20-02-2002"}}

{"names":{"name":"02-02-2010","name_1":"30-01-2010","name_10":"02-09-2006","name_5":"11-11-2011","name_3":"20-02-2002","name_666":"06-06-2006"}}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!